# current time after AVPlayer seek is incorrect

Tags: swift, avplayer

```
func seekFullRead(seconds: Float64, completion: (() -> ())? = nil) {
    let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, preferredTimescale: 60000)
    fullReadPlayer?.currentItem?.seek(to: targetTime, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero, completi[enter image description here][1]onHandler: { (finish) in
        if finish {
            completion?()
        }
    })
}

fullReadTimeObserver = fullReadPlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 10), queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [weak self](time) in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        if self.fullReadPlayer?.status == .readyToPlay {
            self.delegate?.audioPlayer(self, didUpdateCurrentTime: time.seconds, teach: nil)
        }
    })
```

When I seek to 4.57 seconds, the correct current time will be displayed first, then the current time will be 0.2 seconds forward, but playback will start after the current time will be 0.2 seconds forward.

Logs:

current time: 1.30104062

current time: 1.401042787

seek to :  4.579999923706055

current time: 1.498295786

current time: 4.579983333333334

current time: 4.319330793

current time: 4.319642834

current time: 4.401050459

current time: 4.501045084

current time: 4.601038959

Comment: Gonna take a stab. have you tried Pausing playback in your `seekTo:` completion block until and then resume after you fall into your `if(finish){}` block?

Comment: Just to give you an idea why you see this print out. The seek to runs on an asynchronous (a seperate) thread than your timer. Asumming you triggered the seek between 1.4s and 1.5, lets say 1.45. So if that seek thread took more than .05 seconds to complete, your thread that has current time variable will still count 0.1 + the current value. sometime between 1.5 and 1.6 seconds it actually finishes, which is why you see the new time now.

Comment: I have tried to pause before seek, play after seek finish, still the same problem

Comment: @fswedison did you find a way around this? I'm seeing the same exact behaviour when airplaying, seems the currentTime is not updated once the seek completion is executed (but afterwards it gets the proper value) :/

Comment: After seeking, subsequent playback seems to jump back to the start of the nearest audio chunk. I get desired behavior in audio-less video files but as soon as I add audio, I think it wants to start reading audio from the beginning of a buffer. I would prefer it at least gave accurate timing for currentTime and the observer even if it wasn't adhering to the 0 tolerance... seems like a bug

Answer (score 3):

I think NSGangster had the point. Observer timer and seek are on different processes. What this means to me is I will have to handle the discrepancies by myself.

I did not find an answer on the internet and had no luck in finding out a way to make this correct, but I did manage to find a workaround: I could use a variable like 'isSeekInProgress' to mark whether to update the progress bar UI. Illustrated below:

```
var isSeekInProgress: Bool = false  // Marker  

let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, preferredTimescale: 60000)
isSeekInProgress = true // Mark
fullReadPlayer?.currentItem?.seek(to: targetTime, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero, completi[enter image description here][1]onHandler: { (finish) in
    if finish {
        isSeekInProgress = false // Unmark
        completion?()
    }
})
```

Some people pause the player while seeking then resume playback in the completion block, but this won't work in the case you want the playback to keep going while scrubbing. The above example is fairly painless, and all you have to do is check:

```
if !playbackManager.isSeekInProgress {
    progressSlider.value = playbackManager.progress
}
```

And during the next periodic observer notification, your progress will be updated.

Comment: Yep, also didn't find a better solution than just creating a bool marker.